# Angular 6 retry http

Tags: angular, http-status-codes

Is it possible to retry a request, if the status code is 202 ? I know that I can use retryWhen, but that only catches errors.
It would be nice If I somehow could retry from within my interceptor.

I have a request

```
return this.http.get(this.location(location), {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
      res => {
        return res;
      }
    );
```

an interceptor

```
export class HttpLoadInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(event => {
        this.loaderService.displayLoader(true); // show loader
        return event;
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.loaderService.displayLoader(false); // Hide loader
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and a subscribe

```
this._data.flComponent('API url').subscribe(orders => {
  this.flComponent = orders;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but I am not satisfied. It seems that the only option I have is in the subscribe function. Because I use "observe", I get the status etc.

Angular ought to make something similar to retry(), but for whatever status code is returned.

Ex

```
retry(202, 3)
```

Retry, when status code is 202. Retry 3 times